# How to access to external Function from other project in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global

Actually I have a reactJs component which is "**BasicComponent**" that exists in **Project A**(react app)  and inside that I am calling a function  GetGraphObj which exists inside **project B** (javascript(jquery+prototype app)) . 
I can't access to this function althought I set it in package.json 
like : "**globals**" : { "GetGraphObj ":true } .

Here is my BasicComponent :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";   
class BasicComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onhandleChange(e) {
        var fldId = this.props.fldId;
        var global_go = GetGraphObj(fldId);
        console.log(global_go);
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <input
              onChange={e => this.onhandleChange(e)}/>
        )
    }

}
```

Here's the function from the other repository app :

```
function GetGraphObj(fldid) {
    var go = null;
    if (window.graphObjMap[fldid])
    go = window.graphObjMap[fldid]
    else if (eps && eps.graphObjMap[fldid])
    go = eps.graphObjMap[fldid]   
    return go;
}
```

I have even tried to do **window.GetGraphObj**  but seems not working . Have you any idea please how can I **access to external function in reactjs** ?

Comment: Did you try to declare and set the function explicitly on the window object? ```window.GetGraphObj = GetGraphObj```. Alternative is using a module system like UMD or CommonJS. Then this is going to be handled out of the box.